# sentences with '' and,being.....''

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-patterns

> The veins composing the plexus are thin walled **and, being without
> valves,** may pass blood in either direction.

Can this sentence be rewritten as:

> The veins composing the plexus are thin walled **and, *which are*
> being without valves**, may pass blood in either direction.

where ***which*** would refer to ***veins*** ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  The second sentence does not seem _grammatical_ to me, but I don't remember enough of biology class to say whether either one is _true_.  The phrase "being without valves" does refer to the "veins" though.

Comment: Uh… guys, how is is acceptable to use *which are being without valves*, please?

The first example is perfect; the second wrongly drags in *which are* which has no place there.

Please remember, *These sentences are true ? which = veins ??* can be deciphered using raw logic but otherwise, is largely pointless and you should not assume that anything posted here in any way vindicates or agrees with that.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences mean the same thing. As used, I would say that "being" and "which are" mean the same thing (something exists), so the second sentence contains a redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence may be acceptable grammatically, but it looks rather clumsy. I would say

> The veins composing the plexus are thin walled and, ***having no valves***, may pass blood in either direction.

Your second sentence is not acceptable, *which* cannot follow ***and,*** in such a structure. Plus ***are being*** is not appropriate here, as this property does not only apply to the moment of speech. If you really want to rephrase the initial sentence, which is clear and correct as it is, you could say:

> The veins composing the plexus are thin walled and, ***because/as/since they have no valves***, may pass blood in either direction.

Comment: I don't think _having no valves_ is actually a better rendition of the sentence. In any event, that version is not properly punctuated—for it makes the _having no valves_ part parenthetical. Your second version appears better, only that you must add a _they_ before _may pass blood..._ The clause _may pass blood in either direction_ is subjectless otherwise. _because they have no valves_  serves merely as an adverbial here.